# How to stage individual lines in GitAhead

Tags: gitahead

I just started using GitAhead. Have been using SourceTree a lot in the past. In SourceTree you can stage individual lines. I do that all the time. How to do that in GitAhead?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (GitAhead v2.6.1)

There is an open issue about it [gitahead/issues/344](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues/344)